# How to change handler of APT: URLs?

Tags: 10.10, gnome, mime-type, apturl

In Firefox on a fresh install of 10.10 when visiting *apt.ubuntu.com/p/banshee* (for example) I get prompted with the following window:

[image]

However, I was under the impression that apturl was supposed to launch *Software Center*. How can I configure what application apturl is launched with - and is the above screenshot expected actions for 10.10?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that is the default action.

This can be overridden by Firefox, but out of the box the gconf setting
`/desktop/gnome/url-handlers/apt/command` is used. By default that command is `apturl "%s"`.

You can change that by using either using the graphical tool `gconf-editor` or from the command line:

```
gconftool --set --type=string /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/apt/command 'software-center "%s"'
```

This will make Software Center handle apt URLs.

[image]

Comment: Strange, on the box that I'm on `/desktop/gnome/url-handlers/apt/command` is set to `software-center "%s"`. It's not a fresh install. Upgraded all the way to 10.10 from 9.04, and I never changed it. Either way, that's for pointing out the gconf key. I actually want to change it from `software-center` to `apturl` as `software-center` opens so slowly here.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same result using Chromium. I think this window you see is actually the Software Center, prompting for installing the software... Seems this is the default operation when going to a package URL.

Not sure if (or how) you can open the Software Centre itself on the right page :-(