# How to install using the apt:// url on?

Tags: apt, firefox

I ran into this website: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synaptic/ and on it there is a link to be opened with the Ubuntu App center, but Firefox doesn't know what to do with it.

What I got to do to get it opened as it should?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure [apturl](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptURL) in your browser:

In Firefox you need to change the setting also in Preferences->Applications
Link the apt protocol to /usr/bin/apturl there.

Answer (score 1):

You should check that the gconf setting `/desktop/gnome/url-handlers/apt/command` is `software-center "%s"` which is the default.

You can change that by using either using the graphical tool `gconf-editor` or from the command line to `apturl`:

```
gconftool --set --type=string /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/apt/command 'apturl "%s"'
```

or for using the Software Center

```
gconftool --set --type=string /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/apt/command 'software-center "%s"'
```

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/14214/169736